# Why does fork() call this print statement?

Tags: c, fork

On this C program I get output I can't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("%d\n", fork());
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
Hello World
5
Hello World
0
```

My question, is why does it print "Hello World" twice? From my understanding it would print "Hello World" then call fork().

Does fork() start from the beginning of the program?

Comment: "Hello world" was cached, not written. So when second process exits it prints this messsage from the output buffer too. Add `fflush(stdout)` before forking.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the manual page `fork` returns a value to both the parent and child. And it doesn't start from the start of the program.

Please review the manual page for fork